# If Statement not Running

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am fairly new to objective c and cocoa, however i have spent a lot of time with c++, and I have never run across this issue before.

My application needs to identify a mounted disk by name. Here is the code:

```
//this code will run whenever a new disk is mounted to the computer
-(void) scanForKindle:(NSNotification *) notification 
{
    NSMutableArray *mountedDisks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    mountedDisks = [workspace mountedRemovableMedia];
    NSMutableArray *ebookDevices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    int currentDisk;

    for (currentDisk = 0; currentDisk < [mountedDisks count]; currentDisk++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [mountedDisks objectAtIndex:currentDisk]);

        if ([mountedDisks objectAtIndex:currentDisk] == @"/Volumes/Kindle")
        {
            NSLog(@"Kindle has been identified");
        }
    }
}
```

I have gotten everything to work perfectly up to the if statement in the for loop. It simply wont run. any ideas why? I am sure this is a simple fix, but I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you are making pointer comparison between two different instances of `NSString`s.

Do this instead -

```
if ([[mountedDisks objectAtIndex:currentDisk] isEqualToString:@"/Volumes/Kindle"])
{
    NSLog(@"Kindle has been identified");
}
```

Comment: If you know that both objects are strings, you should use `‑isEqualToString:` as it's more efficient.

Comment: The distinction, to clarify it, is that you can have two string objects that contain the same text. `==` tells you whether both sides are the same object; if they are different (i.e., two) objects, then, regardless of what they contain or represent, `==` will evaluate to false: They are not the same object. An `isEqualToString:` message sent to one string object will tell you whether it contains the same text as the other, regardless of whether they are the same object or two objects.

Answer (score 3):

Use NSString's `-isEqualToString:` method to compare strings. `==` just compares the addresses of the strings.